# cloud dataflow cloud sql dataflow runner giving null pointer exception

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm trying to process considerable number of records using cloud dataflow. My source is google cloud storage and my sink is cloud SQL(MySQL). I have the following code to write to the sink(Cloud SQL).

```
p.apply()
....
.withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
                                "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://google/<DBNAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=<USERNAME>&password=<PASSWORD>&useSSL=false"
                            )
                        )
```

The above works fine when I run the pipeline using `DirectRunner`. But it throws a `NullPointer Exception` when run on a `DataflowRunner`. The exception is as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$Write$WriteFn.executeBatch(JdbcIO.java:775)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$Write$WriteFn.finishBundle(JdbcIO.java:755)
```

Beam Version = 2.16.0, 2.15.0 - tried both versions but failed. Any reason why this happens? 
What's the solution to make it work with `DataflowRunner`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this. The `NUllPointerException` is for another reason in the `finishBundle`